# Kubectl / Helm wait for all resources to be created

Tags: continuous-integration, kubernetes-helm, kubectl

I am trying to incorporate testing of a helm chart in my CI pipeline. Effectively I want to install the chart, wait for all resources to come alive, then run some cypress testing.

Currently I am using `helm --wait` and `kubectl wait` commands to effectively wait for deployments, pods, etc. The problem is with a customresource I have that creates a deployment, if the customresource has not created the deployment it will get past all of the waiting without resources being ready.

What I'm looking for is a way to effectively wait until Helm has created all resources from the chart - including the customresources.

Has anyone else run through this or a similar problem? So far my best solution is ugly, but involves parsing a helm dry run to see what resources will be created and then calls to kubectl to wait until they exist. Hoping there's a cleaner way to do this...

Comment: Do you own the chart? If so you can add a post-install hook to the chart to wait for the customresource to create the deployment.

Comment: Yes the chart is custom, so I could make changes. I'm not sure I follow what you're suggesting...adding a post install hook where?

Comment: https://helm.sh/docs/topics/charts_hooks/

Comment: Yes, I'm familiar with chart hooks. I just don't see where adding them would help me in this case. Are you suggesting add a post install hook to my customresource? I am consuming a CRD from elsewhere, so that is not my own and I don't want to touch it.

Comment: If your CRD creates pods with labels attached to it can you run for example `kubectl wait --for=condition=ready pod -l <label-key>=<label-values>`? You can add `--timeout`

Comment: Yes, I appreciate that. I already have proper waiting on all pods being done. The issue is that depending on timing the pod may not exist yet by the time the wait command runs since it is created by a custom resource that creates a statefulset.